# JBoss error "service jboss.network.public (missing) dependents: [service jboss.socket-binding-manager]"?

Tags: jboss

When I starting JBoss - get some errors:

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.network.public (missing) dependents: [service jboss.socket-binding-manager] 

12:33:30,802 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015954: Admin console is not enabled
12:33:30,802 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" 
started (with errors) in 5470ms - Started 106 of 178 services (27 services failed or missing dependencies, 
44 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Can you help me? Thanks

My standalone.xml(parts)

```
<interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:.0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
</interfaces>
```

it is a Socket groups part

Comment: What JBoss version? Look at -b command line option and at <interfaces> and <socket-binding-group> configuration in standalone.xml

Comment: I use JBoss AS 1.7.1

Comment: There's an extra dot in your public interface definition, the `.0.0.0.0` should be `0.0.0.0`

Comment: Thanks, man!!! That's my fault